# Alterar o conteúdo um Span como a mesma Class em uma tabela - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

bom, estou com um problema em uma tabela, onde eu queria que ao clicar no botão de uma certa linha o span específico de onde eu cliquei mudasse de texto, porém não estou conseguindo fazer isto, estarei disponibilizando o código aqui em baixo. PS(Quando clico no botão a linha em específico muda de cor, isto eu consegui, porém na mesma função estou tentando mudar o span). Agradeço desde já!

```
<table class="table table-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Mesa</th>
      <th scope="col">Ocupacidade</th>
      <th scope="col">Status</th>
      <th scope="col">Ocupar Mesa</th>
      <th scope="col">Desocupar Mesa</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="dtable">
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">#1</th>
      <td>2 Pessoas</td>
      <td><span class="badge badge-pill badge-success texto">Disponível</span></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-light disponivel">✔</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-sm ocupado">❌</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">#3</th>
      <td>6 Pessoas</td>
      <td><span class="badge badge-pill badge-success texto">Disponível</span></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-sm disponivel">✔</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-light ocupado">❌</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">#7</th>
      <td>4 Pessoas</td>
      <td><span class="badge badge-pill badge-success texto">Disponível</span></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-sm disponivel">✔</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-light ocupado">❌</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
<script>
    **$("button.ocupado").click(function() {
      $(this).find("span.texto").text('Ocupado');
      $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('row-disponivel');
      $(this).parent().parent().addClass('row-ocupado');
    });**

    $("button.disponivel" ).click(function() {
      $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('row-ocupado');
      $(this).parent().parent().addClass('row-disponivel'); 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código já tinha tudo que precisava.  Veja que pra mudar o style da linha, usou o `this` com referência, que representava o `button`, então usou `parent()` para chegar na `td`, outro `parent()` para chegar na `tr` pra depois remover/adicionar a classe correta, bastava usar isso para encontrar o `span` :)

Veja o exemplo:

```js
$("button.ocupado").click(function() {
      $(this).parent().parent().find("span.texto").text('Ocupado');
      $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('row-disponivel');
      $(this).parent().parent().addClass('row-ocupado');
    });

$("button.disponivel" ).click(function() {
      $(this).parent().parent().find("span.texto").text('Disponível');
      $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('row-ocupado');
      $(this).parent().parent().addClass('row-disponivel'); 
});
```

```css
.row-ocupado {
   background-color: red
}

.row-disponivel {
   background-color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Mesa</th>
      <th scope="col">Ocupacidade</th>
      <th scope="col">Status</th>
      <th scope="col">Ocupar Mesa</th>
      <th scope="col">Desocupar Mesa</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="dtable">
    <tr class="row-disponivel">
      <th scope="row">#1</th>
      <td>2 Pessoas</td>
      <td><span class="badge badge-pill badge-success texto">Disponível</span></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-light disponivel">✔</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-sm ocupado">❌</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-disponivel">
      <th scope="row">#3</th>
      <td>6 Pessoas</td>
      <td><span class="badge badge-pill badge-success texto">Disponível</span></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-sm disponivel">✔</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-light ocupado">❌</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-disponivel">
      <th scope="row">#7</th>
      <td>4 Pessoas</td>
      <td><span class="badge badge-pill badge-success texto">Disponível</span></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-sm disponivel">✔</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-light ocupado">❌</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo, me ajudou demais!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

O find() está buscando o elemento span.texto a partir do button, você precisa descer dois níveis (..td ..tr) para o find() localizar o span.texto.

Ficaria assim:

```js
$(this).parent().parent().find("span.texto").text('Ocupado');
```

O mesmo para o button.disponivel

```js
$(this).parent().parent().find("span.texto").text('Disponível');
```

Espero que ajude.
Abs.

Comment: Obrigado por me ajudar amigo :).